# how do i decipher 4 byte data split them accordingly and assign them to a meaningful variable?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, logical-operators

I have 4 byte data stream, I know at what bite I wanted to split them and assign them to a different variable. keeping in mind the data I receive is in hex format. let's say,

```
P_settings  4bytes   p_timeout  [6:0]
                    p_s_detected[7]

                    p_o_timeout [14:8]
                    p_o_timeout_set [15]

                    override_l_lvl  [23:16]
                    l_b_lvl [31:24]
```

above  P_settings is 4 bytes and I wanted to split them byte into bits like `p_timeout  [6:0] requires 7 bits of those 4 byte.`

Currently, the implementation I have tried is..for just one byte split into bits.

```
 var soch = ((b_data>> 0)& 0x7F ); if i want first 7 bits
```

how do I do it for 4 byte streams

Comment: Have you thought of using a uint? It's 32 bits. Generally, if the bits you want are split over different bytes in a 4-byte value you don't need to worry about the fact that they're in separate bytes. i.e. byte result = ((b_data & 0x000ff000) >> 12) would pull out bits 12 - 20.

Answer (score 1):

Try code like this.  You said input was a stream.

```
    public class P_Settings
    {
        byte  p_timeout; //[6:0]
        Boolean p_s_detected; //[7]

        byte  p_o_timeout; // [14:8]
        Boolean p_o_timeout_set; // [15]

        byte override_l_lvl; //[23:16]
        byte l_b_lvl; //[31:24]

        public P_Settings(Stream data)
        {
            byte input = (byte)(data.ReadByte() & 0xff);
            p_timeout = (byte)(input & 0x7F);
            p_s_detected = (input & 0x80) == 0 ? false : true;

            input = (byte)(data.ReadByte() & 0xff);
            p_o_timeout = (byte)(input & 0x7F);
            p_o_timeout_set = (input & 0x80) == 0 ? false : true;

            override_l_lvl = (byte)(data.ReadByte() & 0xff);
            l_b_lvl = (byte)(data.ReadByte() & 0xff);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

SO it turns out it much easier that i thought.. 
1) separate them by single byte and put them in a buffer and & operate them individually and you will get the data. thanks for all the support.

**

```
                byte input = (byte)( buffer[10]);//1 byte
                var p_timeout = (byte)(input & 0x7F);
                var p_s_detected = (input & 0x80) == 0 ? false : true;

                 input = (byte)( buffer[11]);//1 byte
                var p_o_timeout = (byte)(input & 0x7F);
                var p_o_timeout_set = (input & 0x80) == 0 ? false : true;

                var override_l_lvl = (byte)(buffer[12] & 0xff);//1 byte
                var l_b_lvl = (byte)(buffer[13] & 0xff);  //1 byte
```

**